# How can we find the real part of $(1-i)^{5/3}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

I am currently evaluating 
$$I = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^3}\cos(x^3) \ \mathrm{d}x,$$
and by use of the real part of $e^{ix^3}$ and the gamma function, I have narrowed $I$ down to
$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{6}\Re\left(1-i\right)^{\frac{5}{3}}.$$ My attempts have been limited for the $\Re\left(1-i\right)^{\frac{5}{3}}$. I have tried the following equality
$$\left(1-i\right)^{\frac{5}{3}} = \left(a+bi\right),$$ but I think my intuition may be blatantly wrong because I cannot see how I can get any further from here... unless what if I were to first raise the LHS to the 5th power, expand it using the binomial theorem, and then take the cube root? Then I would have to raise $(a+bi)^3$ at some later point. Maybe this will work. I'll update my post after I try this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you transform the number $1-i$ into its polar form you'll get $\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{7\pi}{4}}$.  Then from here you get

$$
(1-i)^{5/3} \;\; =\;\; \left (2^{1/2} e^{i\frac{7\pi}{4}}\right )^{5/3} \;\; =\;\; 2^{5/6} e^{i\frac{35\pi}{12}}.
$$

The real part of this is

$$
2^{5/6}\cos\left (\frac{35\pi}{12}\right ) \;\; =\;\; 2^{5/6}\cos\left (\frac{11\pi}{12}\right )
$$

where we note the equivalence since $\frac{35\pi}{12} \sim \frac{35\pi}{12} - 2\pi$.  If we observe that we can break up $\frac{11\pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{2\pi}{3}$ then we can break down the cosine term:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos\left (\frac{11\pi}{12}\right ) & = & \cos\left (\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{2\pi}{3}\right ) \\
&  = & \cos\left (\frac{\pi}{4}\right )\cos\left (\frac{2\pi}{3}\right ) - \sin\left (\frac{\pi}{4}\right )\sin\left (\frac{2\pi}{3}\right ) \\
& = & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left ( -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}    \right ) \\
& = & -\frac{\sqrt{2}\left (1 + \sqrt{3}\right )}{4} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

The final answer is $-\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2^{2/3}}$.

Comment: The integral is entirely real:
$$\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{6\cdot 2^{2/3}}$$

Comment: Ahhh alright. I did not even consider taking this into it's polar form. I assume it's a standard convention, I am just getting used to complex analysis, haha, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$1-i=e^{2n\pi i-i\pi/4} 2^{1/2}$$

$$(1-i)^{5/3}=e^{5(8n-1)i\pi/12}2^{5/6}/=f(n)$$ where $n=0,1,2$

So the principal value will be $$f(0)$$